# Java ArrayQueue enqueue and dequeue throwing arrayQueueException

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I was having some problem when trying to dequeue from an ArrayQueue> variable type to ArrayQueue and pass it as a parameter to another method.

So basically I got two methods, one is sort() with no parameter and the other one is merge() which takes in 2 ArrayQueue parameters.

I got a global variable called Queue:

```
private ArrayQueue<ArrayQueue<E>> Queue;
```

And inside my sort(), I am dequeueing the first two items from Queue and pass them to merge() as parameters:

```
public void sort() {
    while (Queue.size() >= 2) {
        ArrayQueue<E> first = Q.dequeue();
        ArrayQueue<E> second = Q.dequeue();
        System.out.print("1st" + firstElement);
        System.out.print("2nd" + secondElement);
         merge(first,second)
    }
}

public E dequeue() throws ArrayQueueException {
    if (isEmpty() == true)
        throw new ArrayQueueException("Queue error");
    if (front == rear) {
        front = front - 1;
        rear = rear - 1;
    } else
        front = front + 1;
    size--;
    return Q[front];
}
```

Then inside my merge:

```
private ArrayQueue<E> merge(ArrayQueue<E> q1, ArrayQueue<E> q2) throws ArrayQueueException {
    System.out.println("q1 is " + q1.toString());
    ArrayQueue<E> merged = new ArrayQueue<E>();
    String e1 = (String) q1.dequeue();
    System.out.println("e1 is " + e1);
    String e2 = (String) q2.dequeue();

    merged.enqueue(q2.dequeue());
            if (q2.isEmpty()) {
                // add remaining q1 elements
                while (!q1.isEmpty()) {
                    merged.enqueue(q1.dequeue());
                }
                break;
            }
            // take another element from q2
            e2 = (String) q2.dequeue();
}
```

And the output that I get from console is:

```
1st[the]2nd[ragged]q1 is [the]
e1 is null
Exception in thread "main" ArrayQueueException: Queue error
at ArrayQueue.dequeue(ArrayQueue.java:84)
at QueueSort.merge(QueueSort.java:41)
at QueueSort.sort(QueueSort.java:73)
at QueueSort.main(QueueSort.java:122)
```

QueueSort.java:41 is this line: merged.enqueue(q2.dequeue()); I not sure why it won't dequeue.

Also, I not sure why the e1 became null because I was trying to perform a dequeue and cast it to string. I need this string for the later part.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An `ArrayQueue` is not a general JDK utility class. It actually comes from the `com.sun.jmx.remote.internal` package, and is therefore undocumented and should not be used by client code. The correct class here probably is [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) (or `LinkedList`, whatever you prefer)

Comment: @Slanec It's actually an assignment and we have to follow what they told. Do you have any ideas how to fix it based on the criteria above? Because the ArrayQueue parameter for merge() only contain one string for each so I was thinking is it possible to dequeue it from the parameter and enqueue back to another queue as the code above? I was thinking is it because that part is causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem appears to be your dequeue function. It is always returning isEmpty(). I would check on the isempty() and check the size right before you get to that point. I don't see any items being enqueued to the ArrayQueue before you try to dequeue. It is possible you have your q1 and q2 set up but you don't put any items on those so it is returning nothing.

One possible problem is the variable name for your queue. The Queue is an interface and it is possible things are getting confused in the sort before you pass it to the dequeue. You should change the name of the Queue to queue or something more distinct. It is best to always have variables that begin lowercase.

Also, for style, in your dequeue function the isEmpty() does not need to be compared to true if you return a boolean from it. It would just look like:

```
if (isEmpty())
```

The isEmpty() function resolves to true or false and the if statement acts on that value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, but I realized that the problem now is let's say my q1 contains [the] and q2 contains [hello]. But then when I need these two to be added into another ArrayQueue called merged. The only way to add them into the merged is to enqueue. But in order to enqueue it, I need q1 and q2 to dequeue first. But then again, because q1 and q2 only have 1 item and that's why when dequeue it runs into the isEmpty

Comment: Shouldn't q1 and q2 be able to be empty? When they dequeue the single item it should dequeue properly. You should be able to use it in your enqueue. It seems like your isEmpty() function might be returning true when there is only one item in it.